# Invalid conversion from void* when using SelectObject

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Hello I am trying to create a brush but I am having problem with SelectObject this line of code:

```
Brush_C = SelectObject(hdc_TS, hBrush);
```

The error is like this:

```
line 231: error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `HBRUSH__*'
```

How do I do to get it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple cast will fix that for you:

```
Brush_C = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc_TS, hBrush);
```

Comment: Would that simple Google search have told you that you shouldn't use C-style casts in C++? (Yes, yes it would have.)

Comment: So what would have been your solution then?